# Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::storeload()?

Tags: php

Here is the corresponding line:

```
$request->metaUser->meta->storeload();
```

Can anybody explain what the problem is here, and how to solve it please?

Comment: there is no method named `storeload` in `request` class

Comment: Probably you don't have this function defined. Give us some more info here, what tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like "meta" property is an instance of "stdClass" which obviously doesn't have "storeload()" method.